# Can I require (the simpler way) to copy the resultant config-file of my dll instead of post-build event using?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, project

My solution contains two projects. One of them is console application, but second is dll. Each of them has own output directory. Both projects contains `App.config` files. Their names in the output directories are `MyConsoleApp.exe.config` and `MyLibrary.dll.config`. Console application has the reference to the second project (its `Copy Local` property is `True`).

But compilation result of console application not contains the `config`-file of my `dll` in the console application output directory. Therefore I copy it through the *post-build event* of my console application.

Can I require (*the simpler way*) to copy the resultant `config`-file of my `dll` *instead of* post-build event using?

Comment: Dll config file will not exist. The dll configurations have to be putted in app.config file

Comment: You are not right. I haven't problem with it for my WCF clients and services. It works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not. Application configuration files are not seen as a dependency of another project. Hence, they are not copied.

I am not sure if you really need that file, but if you do, you could keep your current post-build action. Another option would be to create it from your application if it doesn't exist and default the setting values from there.

Comment: My DLL contains the set of WCF-services. Their settings are located in the config-file of the DLL. I don't want edit the config-file of the host application therefore I store settings of my services in the separate config-file (my DLL is extension of the application).

Comment: No, I don't want to edit my code source and rebuild DLL every time when it will be necessary to edit configuration settings.

Comment: I understand, I guess our deployment was totally opposite (I had to deliver a product that would run out of the box for a lot of installations, where you don't want to change config for every client). If the only thing that changes is the URL, you can load that part from somewhere else.

Comment: Still then, my answer remains valid. There is no other way than to copy the file around.